# How does Java EE application starts executing without any main method and how does control goes to different classes

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, ejb, persistence

How does Java EE application starts executing without any main method and how does control goes to different classes like EJB,Session,Persistence class etc. As per my understanding it starts with JSF or jsp page. Can someone elaborate as i am new to Java EE apps.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept of Java EE. It uses an application server that is started. After that it usualy waits for a user action before it kicks of any business logic. So it's not run and it will do some business logic. You could however run business logic directly with annotating your class with `@Singleton @Startup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java EE Servers or Java Servlet containers have a `public static void main` method which starts up the program.  After that, most servers allocate a certain number of threads that listen and handle requests

Comment: where can I find details about Java EE server working?

Comment: On the web sites of the various EE Servers.  Try Oracle WebLogic, Tomcat, JBoss, Tomcat,  Glassfish.  You can even download the source code of Tomcat and Glassfish